# phpbb3 after username is acceptable inject code

Tags: php, phpbb, phpbb3

I have a list of reserved usernames that I would like to prevent new users from using before I've had a chance to authenticate them. Authentication would be done by putting a secret code on a website I will then check the website for the code and allow them to continue. I have already written the methods to authenticate the codes but...

First: Reading functions_user.php I can't figure out where the last username check is to look at my list of users. I've been all over the file and I can't even see where they validate the username against the database. (This is more important than the second part)

Second: I need to add the authentication key somewhere (I could probably just write it to a flat file since the list only has about 150 names) - does anyone have some suggestions for that?

#### Update

I think I can just ignore the method `user_add` and do the check before it even gets there - I'll give that a try.

Actually, after thinking about it some more I think I need to create the user with the secret key already and if anyone tries to login with one of the users I'll give them the key to authenticate and go from there...

Answer (score 1):

err, this is really confused.

Preventing code injection using a blacklist is a waste of a LOT of time and computing expense. The right way to fix the problem is to [escape the content according to the medium where it being written](http://xkcd.com/327/).

If you are using off-the-shelf code that you don't really trust, then try something like...

```
function is_nasty($str)
{
   if (htmlentities($str)!==$str) {
       return true;
   }
   if (mysql_escape_string($str)!==$str) {
       return true;
   }
   // any more checks you want to run....
   return false;
}
```